Android Peripheral BluetoothGattServerCallback onCharacteristicWriteRequest() not getting called
I am working on a BLE peripheral app that connect to a central device and encounters a data lost issue.
In my Android application, I am using three ATT characteristics.
//Server send data to Client using Notification

BluetoothGattCharacteristic char_tx = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(MCHP_BLE_UART_TX,
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY,
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE);

//Client send data to Server using ATT_WRITE_CMD

BluetoothGattCharacteristic char_rx = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(MCHP_BLE_UART_RX,
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE,
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE);

//Credit control. Credit is used for flow control 
Client send credit to Server using ATT_WRITE_REQUEST

BluetoothGattCharacteristic char_control = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(MCHP_BLE_UART_CONTROL,
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY,
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE);

Notification is working as expected.
I discovered that the ATT write command sent from client to server will be lost
Test phone: Samsung A54 5G/Android 13. The same problem also occurs on another android phone: Galaxy S22/Android 12
Test step: Client(Device) send credit and data to Server(APP).
Test result:
My peripheral app compares the transmitted and received data and shows that the data is incorrect.
Check BT air log and HCI log, the transmitted data is correct.
Finally, I found the BluetoothGattServerCallback onCharacteristicWriteReuest function is not called. It occurs when the Server receives an ATT write request and receives another ATT write command before Server replies with a write response. It can be seen in the BTSnoop log. Frame 1440, 1443, 1444

If the server receives the write command after replying to the write response, this problem will not occur.
My question is why the onCharacteristicWriteReuest callback is not called? I use the different characteristics to transmit data.
Is this a limitation of Android BLE peripheral APIs or a bug? I tried to google about the Android ble peripheral and usage of peripheral APIs but could not find it.

Your code shows that you send data with option PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE. How should Android then know when the write request has been finished
and it is time to call onCharacteristicWriteRequest() without a response from the receiving device? In my understanding using this option enable the "fire and furget" mode. If you don't want it this way don't use it.
